# AES one-shot API decryption throwing if it has not encrypted before

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes, .net-6.0

I'm attempting to roundtrip crypting some data with the [new .NET 6 AES one-shot APIs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/2406).

The following example works as expected:

```cs
using System.Security.Cryptography;

string key = "1234567890123456";
byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);

string dec = "Hello One-Shot API!";
byte[] decBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dec);

// Encrypt
using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
byte[] encBytes = aes.EncryptCbc(decBytes, keyBytes);

// Decrypt again
byte[] recBytes = aes.DecryptCbc(encBytes, keyBytes);
string rec = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBytes);

Debug.Assert(rec == dec);
```

But if I create a *new* `Aes` instance to call `DecryptCbc` on, it throws a `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.` exception:

```cs
...
// Encrypt
using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
byte[] encBytes = aes.EncryptCbc(decBytes, keyBytes);

// Decrypt again - this time with new instance
using Aes aes2 = Aes.Create();
byte[] recBytes = aes2.DecryptCbc(encBytes, keyBytes); // <- throws
...
```

Am I missing something here? Is there state set up in an `Aes` instance when calling `EncryptCbc` that doesn't exist when only using it for decryption? Do I have to keep the `Aes` instance around, and then how would I use it for decryption initially if I haven't encrypted with it before?

Comment: I think it's because the second argument to `DecryptCbc` is not the key but the IV.

Comment: You're right! I didn't bother about any IV since the code I'm porting is very old and uses no IV. I'll adjust the code and post a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I mistook the *IV* parameter for the key, as I was porting old code not using any IV.

Once setting the key in the `Aes.Key` property, and using an empty IV (or even better, fixing the old code and using a proper IV), it worked as expected with every new instance.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
string key = "12345678901234567890123456789012"; // 32 length
private string Encrypt(string text, string key){
  byte[] encText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
  
  using(Aes enc = Aes.Create()){
    enc.key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(enc.EncryptCbc(encText , new byte[16]));
  }
}

private string Decrypt(string hashText, string key){
  byte[] encText = Convert.FromBase64String(hashText);

  using(Aes enc = Aes.Create()){
    enc.key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    byte[] decrypt = enc.DecryptCbc(encText, new byte[16]);
    
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypt);
  }
}
```